# stream_context_create certificate verify failed

Tags: php, ssl, curl, stream

I'm trying to connect securely to this server `bch.curalle.ovh` port `50002`

I have a certificate from letsencrypt which located at `/var/www/mywebsite/fullchain.pem`

my code:

```
$context = stream_context_create([ 'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'verify_peer_name' => true,
                'cafile' => '/var/www/mywebsite/fullchain.pem',
            ]
    ]);

$connection = stream_socket_client("ssl://bch.curalle.ovh:50002" , $errorn , $errorstr , 5 , STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT , $context);
```

Error Response:

```
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed 
Failed to enable crypto
```

I have changed my certificate to the one that CURL provides but the same exact error.

Comment: have you configured your server to use that certificate? seems not.

Comment: Do you mean the server that I'm connecting to? the server that runs my application is configured to use that certificate and HTTPS protocol working.

Comment: https://bch.curalle.ovh:50002/ - not for me

Comment: Yeah that is not my server. I had the same issue with google smtp

Answer (score 1):

What cause this problem the following:

- the server is not configured use SSL certificate (@Federkun).
- Server that i'm connecting from has incorrect date.

I've fixed it by installing ntpdate and running `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` on ubuntu